# VBA - Apply document formatting to open Word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using data in an Excel workbook to create an HTML string when a user clicks a button. I then use VBA to save that string as an .html file, open it in Word, and bring Word to the foreground. That all works great.

Now, I'd like to add a line(s) to the VBA to select the document formatting.

In the Word doc that opens, there's this in the ribbon:

[image]

When I hover over that formatting option, it's called "Lines (simple)." I can click it in Word, and it formats the text exactly how I want it. But, I'd like to do so automatically with the VBA over in Excel that created and launched the Word document. Unfortunately I just don't know which command or property that is and haven't been able to find it with searches or document inspection. I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and then adapting the resultant code.

Comment: @freeflow I'm a VBA beginner but that sounds like a great idea! Thank you.

Comment: It seems to me you're going about this entirely the wrong way. If you were to create a Word template with all the formatted boilerplate content in-situ, with suitable tags wherever the variable data are to go, all you'd need to do is to create a new document from the template (via Word's .Documents.Add method), then update the tags.

Comment: The way I'm going about it is a client requirement. It doesn't allow for a fill-in-the-blank approach. The entire content of the document is dynamic and generated from scratch.